# Compilation error: no type named 'type' within Boost.Range / MPL

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

When compiling the following code below, the compiler (clang 10.0.1) generates `error: no type named 'type'...` deep within the [Boost.Range](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html) library dependencies of `boost::adaptors::transformed`

How should I change my template function `result_data_type` in order to avoid this compiler error?

The source code is;

```
struct request_data {
    std::string data;
    size_t      length = 0;
};

struct error {
    std::string message;
};

template <typename T> 
using result_value = boost::variant<T, error>;

template <typename T> 
auto result_data_type(result_value<T>&& input) -> result_value<T> {
    return boost::apply_visitor(
        make_visitor([](const T& req) { return req; },
                     [](const error&) {
                         throw std::runtime_error("SHOULD_NEVER_HAPPEN");
                         return T();
                     }),
        input);
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(template_test) {
    using result_data = result_value<request_data>;

    const auto vec_in =
        std::vector<result_data>{result_data{request_data{"Hi", 2}},
                                 result_data{request_data{"there!", 6}}};
    auto vec_out =
        vec | boost::adaptors::transformed(result_data_type<request_data>);
}
```

And the full error output is;

```
[main] Building folder: aljam 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake --build /Users/alan/github/aljam/build --config Debug --target aljam -- -j 6
[build] Scanning dependencies of target aljam
[build] [  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/aljam.dir/cpp_playground/aljam.cpp.o
[build] In file included from /Users/alan/github/aljam/cpp_playground/aljam.cpp:9:
[build] In file included from /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/test/unit_test.hpp:18:
[build] In file included from /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/test/test_tools.hpp:46:
[build] In file included from /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/test/tools/old/impl.hpp:28:
[build] In file included from /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/numeric/conversion/conversion_traits.hpp:13:
[build] In file included from /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/numeric/conversion/detail/conversion_traits.hpp:17:
[build] In file included from /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/numeric/conversion/detail/meta.hpp:16:
[build] /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:38:26: error: no type named 'type' in 'boost::result_of<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*const &(const boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &))(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&)>'
[build]     typedef typename f_::type type;
[build]             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
[build] /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp:149:9: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::is_same<boost::use_default, boost::use_default>, boost::result_of<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*const &(const boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &))(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&)>, boost::mpl::identity<boost::use_default> >' requested here
[build]       : mpl::eval_if<
[build]         ^
[build] /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp:48:26: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::iterators::detail::ia_dflt_help<boost::use_default, boost::result_of<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*const &(const boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &))(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&)> >' requested here
[build]         typedef typename ia_dflt_help<
[build]                          ^
[build] /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp:80:40: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::iterators::detail::transform_iterator_base<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*)(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&), std::__1::__wrap_iter<const boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> *>, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>' requested here
[build]     : public boost::iterators::detail::transform_iterator_base<UnaryFunc, Iterator, Reference, Value>::type
[build]                                        ^
[build] /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp:33:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*)(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&), std::__1::__wrap_iter<const boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> *>, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>' requested here
[build]                     typename transform_iterator<P, It>::reference
[build]                              ^
[build] /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp:42:26: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::range_detail::transform_iterator_gen<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*)(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&), std::__1::__wrap_iter<const boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> *> >' requested here
[build]                 typename transform_iterator_gen<
[build]                          ^
[build] /Users/alan/github/aljam/cpp_playground/aljam.cpp:564:13: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::range_detail::transformed_range<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*)(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&), const std::__1::vector<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error>, std::__1::allocator<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> > > >' requested here
[build]         vec | boost::adaptors::transformed(result_data_type<request_data>);
[build]             ^
[build] In file included from /Users/alan/github/aljam/cpp_playground/aljam.cpp:19:
[build] In file included from /Users/alan/github/aljam/functional/range.hpp:17:
[build] /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp:57:20: error: no type named 'reference' in 'boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*)(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&), std::__1::__wrap_iter<const boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> *>, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>'
[build]                 >::reference
[build]                 ~~~^~~~~~~~~
[build] /Users/alan/github/aljam/cpp_playground/aljam.cpp:564:13: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::range_detail::transformed_range<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*)(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&), const std::__1::vector<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error>, std::__1::allocator<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> > > >' requested here
[build]         vec | boost::adaptors::transformed(result_data_type<request_data>);
[build]             ^
[build] In file included from /Users/alan/github/aljam/cpp_playground/aljam.cpp:19:
[build] In file included from /Users/alan/github/aljam/functional/range.hpp:17:
[build] /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp:96:19: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'transformed_range<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*)(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&), const std::__1::vector<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error>, std::__1::allocator<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> > > >'
[build]            return transformed_range<UnaryFunction, const SinglePassRange>(
[build]                   ^
[build] /Users/alan/github/aljam/cpp_playground/aljam.cpp:564:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::range_detail::operator|<std::__1::vector<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error>, std::__1::allocator<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> > >, boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*)(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&)>' requested here
[build]         vec | boost::adaptors::transformed(result_data_type<request_data>);
[build]             ^
[build] /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp:62:13: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*const)(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&)' to 'boost::range_detail::transformed_range<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> (*)(boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> &&), const std::__1::vector<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error>, std::__1::allocator<boost::variant<aljam::request_data, aljam::error> > > >::transform_fn_type' (aka 'int') for 1st argument
[build]             transformed_range(transform_fn_type f, R& r)
[build]             ^
[build] /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp:40:16: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
[build]         struct transformed_range :
[build]                ^
[build] /Users/alan/github/boost_1_73_0/boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp:40:16: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
[build] 3 errors generated.
[build] make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/aljam.dir/cpp_playground/aljam.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/aljam.dir/all] Error 2
[build] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/aljam.dir/rule] Error 2
[build] make: *** [aljam] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a case of an unhelpful error message completely missing the cause of the problem.

After rewriting your last line as

```
auto vec_out = vec_in | boost::adaptors::transformed([](auto& result_data){ return result_data_type<request_data>(result_data); });
```

I received the much more helpful error message:

```
test.cc:68:118: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘result_value<request_data>&&’ {aka ‘std::variant<request_data, error>&&’} to lvalue of type ‘const std::variant<request_data, error>’
```

Changing `result_data_type` to take a `const result_value<T>&` instead of `result_value<T>&&` fixes the compile error.

Comment: Got similar error while working with asio: `no type named 'type' in 'boost::asio::constraint<false, boost::asio::awaitable<int>>'` and rvalue was the issue